# For loop and addition methods with lists on Python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, integer, addition

I'm creating a sudoku solver with backtracking. Now, I need to add 1 to each cell. I'm using a "for" loop:

```
board = [[[0],[0],[0],[0]],
          [[0],[0],[0],[0]],
          [[0],[0],[0],[0]],
          [[0],[0],[0],[0]]]`

a=0
b=0
x=board[a][b]`

for i in x:
    x.append(i+1)
    y = [sum(x)]
    print(y)
    break
board[a][b] = y
```

What happens is that, if I have a number on the board, like "2", it does the operation of `(1+1)+(1+1) +1`, and returns 5 instead of 3. I get 9 from 4 `[(1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1)+1)]`, etc.

I'm thinking about solving it by converting "x" from a list to an integer, then adding 1 and then reconverting it in a list.

Any more efficient and time saving ideas?

(I want to keep, if possible, the list structure of "board", but I'm open to any suggestion, of course.)

EDIT:

If i have this:

```
board = [[[0],[3],[2],[0]],
          [[0],[0],[0],[0]],
          [[0],[0],[0],[0]],
          [[0],[0],[0],[0]]]`
```

I want it to end like this:

```
board = [[[1],[4],[3],[1]],
          [[1],[1],[1],[1]],
          [[1],[1],[1],[1]],
          [[1],[1],[1],[1]]]`
```

Instead, I get:

```
board = [[[1],[7],[5],[1]],
          [[1],[1],[1],[1]],
          [[1],[1],[1],[1]],
          [[1],[1],[1],[1]]]`
```

SOLUTION:

```
for i in x:
    x.append(1)  #Quite simple
```

Thanks James!

Comment: just to clarify, you want all the cells to contain 1 instead of 0 after the loop?

Comment: In the first case yes, that's what it does. But when it comes to cells that already have a number different than 0, I get wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass the number 1 into x.append(), that should accumulate a one in each cell.